# Java - Create reference to two models in a custom adapter

Tags: java, android, model, adapter, custom-adapter

I have two models called `Buyer` and `Car`, and a custom layout called `custom_row` to display the rows of a `ListView`.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Buyer> buyers;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Buyer> buyers) {
        this.c = c;
        this.buyers = buyers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return buyers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return buyers.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        }

        TextView tvBuyerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvBuyerName);
        TextView tvCarModel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCarModel);

        final Buyer b = (Buyer) this.getItem(position);

        tvBuyerName.setText(b.getBuyerName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

So far I've only done above code, and I'm only able to display buyer's name. How to create another reference in `ArrayList` to model `Car`, so that I can get and display the information from both model `Buyer` and model `Car` in a same `ListView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is create a model which contains both **Car & Buyer** data.
By that yo can access car and buyer from same arraylist.

Another is pass two arraylist (carList & buyerList) to constructor of adapter.

```
ArrayList<Buyer> buyers;
ArrayList<Car> cars;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Buyer> buyers, ArrayList<Car> cars) {
        this.c = c;
        this.buyers = buyers;
        this.cars= cars;
    }
```

Then

```
final Buyer b = (Buyer) buyers.getItem(position);
tvBuyerName.setText(b.getBuyerName());

final Car c = (Car) cars.getItem(position);
tvCar.setText(c.getCarName());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new class with `Buyer` and `Car` as attributes:

```
class Transaction{
    public Buyer buyer;
    public Car car;
}
```

and use it in your `ArrayList` (`ArrayList<Transaction>`).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of create ArrayList of `Buyer` create ArrayList of `Pair<Buyer,Car>` like this:

```
ArrayList<Pair<Buyer,Car>> myBuyAndCarPair;
```

And when you wish to get the `Buyer` or the `Car` Objects call them like this:

```
Buyer myBuyer = myBuyAndCarPair.get(i).first;
Car myCar = myBuyAndCarPair.get(i).second;
```

To create new pair:

```
new Pair<>(mBuyerObject,mCarObject);
```